# Creating sqlite database on eclipse

Tags: android, database, eclipse, sqlite

I'm currently trying to create a database on eclipse. The user will be able to type his/her name and save it in the database. Besides that, the save data will be shown in the next page.

I've encounter error and not sure if the codes is correct. 
I got help from here: [database](https://github.com/Balu-Varanasi/BabyNamesApp/tree/master/src/balu/android/database)

Below is my code:

main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="Enter your name below:" 
/>

<EditText
android:id="@+id/nameText"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
/>

<Button
android:id="@+id/saveButton"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="Save" 
/>

</LinearLayout>
```

solution.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/android:list">
</ListView>
```

SaveData.java

```
package com.mp.Testing;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;

public class SaveData extends SQLiteOpenHelper 
{
// Name & the version of Database.
public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "saveData_database";
public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

// Names of the Tables in Database
public static final String DATABASE_TABLE_1 = "pictures";
public static final String DATABASE_TABLE_2 = "data";

// Columns present in DATABASE_TABLE_1
public static final String PICTURES_ROWID = "_id";
public static final String PICTURES_FILE = "pictures_file";
public static final String DATA_NAME = "_name";
public static final String DATA_LANGTITUDE = "pictures_langtitude";
public static final String DATA_LONGTITUDE = "pictures_longtitude";

// SQL query string for creating DATABASE_TABLE_1
static final String CREATE_DATABASE_TABLE_1 =
           "create table " + DATABASE_TABLE_1 + " (" + PICTURES_ROWID + 
           " integer primary key autoincrement, " +
           " " + PICTURES_FILE + " text not null);";

// To execute the SQL command
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase database) 
{
    database.execSQL(DATABASE_TABLE_1);
    Log.d("SaveData", "Created DB");
}

public static final String TAG_1 = "PICTURES_TABLE";

private Context context;

// Constructor
public SaveData(Context context) 
{
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    this.context = context;
}

// Upgrading the database version
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) 
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub  
}

// Inserting pictures into database
private void insertDataIntoPictures(SQLiteDatabase db) 
{
    try
    {
        InputStream is = context.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.picture);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        String strLine = null;

        while ((strLine = (br.readLine()).trim()) != null) 
        {
            String[] temp = null;

            ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();

            initialValues.put(PICTURES_FILE, temp[0].trim());

            db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE_1, null, initialValues);
        }

        is.close();
    }   
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Log.d(TAG_1, "Error while inserting common names into table");
    }
}

// Inserting data into database
private void insertDataIntoData(SQLiteDatabase db) 
{
    try
    {
        InputStream is = context.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.data); 
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        String strLine = null;

        while ((strLine = (br.readLine()).trim()) != null) 
        {
            String[] temp = null;

            ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();

            initialValues.put(DATA_LANGTITUDE, temp[0]);
            initialValues.put(DATA_LONGTITUDE, temp[1]);

            db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE_1, null, initialValues);
        }

        is.close();
    }   
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Log.d(TAG_1, "Error while inserting common names into table");
    }
}
}
```

DataAdapter.java

```
package com.mp.Testing;

import com.mp.Testing.DataAdapter;
import com.mp.Testing.SaveData;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.util.Log;

public class DataAdapter 
{
// Database table name
public static final String DATABASE_TABLE_1 = "pictures";

// Columns present in DATABASE_TABLE_1
public static final String PICTURES_ROWID = "_id";
public static final String PICTURES_FILE = "pictures_file";
public static final String PICTURES_COUNT = "pictures_count";

// Object for SQLiteDatabase
private SQLiteDatabase database;

// 
public static final String TAG = "COMMON_NAMES_TABLE";

// Creating variable
private SaveData save_data;

public DataAdapter() 
{

}

// Open connection of database
public DataAdapter open(Context context) throws SQLException
{
    Log.i(TAG, "OPening DataBase Connection....");
    save_data = new SaveData(context);
    database = save_data.getWritableDatabase();
    return this;
}

// Close connection of database
public void close() 
{
    database.close();
}

// Delete the pictures ID
public boolean deletePictures(long rowId) 
{
    return database.delete(DATABASE_TABLE_1, PICTURES_ROWID + "=" + rowId, null) > 0;
}

// Fetching all the pictures
public Cursor fetchAllPictures() 
{
    return database.query(DATABASE_TABLE_1, new String[] {PICTURES_ROWID, PICTURES_FILE}, null, null, null, null, PICTURES_ROWID);
}

// Fetching the pictures
public Cursor fetchPictures(long commonNameId) throws SQLException 
{
    Cursor mCursor = database.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE_1, new String[] 
    {
        PICTURES_ROWID, PICTURES_FILE}, PICTURES_ROWID + "=" +
        commonNameId, null, null, null, null, null);

        if(mCursor != null) 
        {
            mCursor.moveToFirst();
        }
    return mCursor;
}

// Fetching pictures
public Cursor fetch_all_pictures() 
{
    return database.query(DATABASE_TABLE_1, new String[] {PICTURES_ROWID, PICTURES_FILE}, null, null, null, null, null);
}

// Update the database
public boolean updatePictures(int commonNameId, String commonName, String commonNameCount) 
{
    ContentValues args = new ContentValues();
    args.put(PICTURES_FILE, commonName);
    args.put(PICTURES_COUNT, commonNameCount);

    return database.update(DATABASE_TABLE_1, args, PICTURES_ROWID + "=" + commonNameId, null) > 0;
}
}
```

Testing.java

```
package com.mp.Testing;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;

public class Testing extends ListActivity 
{
DataAdapter cnTable;
ListView cnListView;
Cursor c;

private static final int DATA_ACTIVITY_START = 1;
private static final int PICTURES_ACTIVITY_START = 0;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.solution);

    cnTable = new DataAdapter();
    cnTable.open(getApplicationContext());

    c = cnTable.fetchAllPictures();
    startManagingCursor(c);

    if(c!=null)
    {
        SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
        R.layout.solution, c,
        new String[] {c.getColumnName(1)},
        new int[] {R.id.saveButton});
        setListAdapter(adapter);
    }
}

@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) 
{
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);

    c.moveToPosition(position);

    Intent i = new Intent(this, Testing.class);
    i.putExtra(DataAdapter.PICTURES_ROWID, id);
    i.putExtra(DataAdapter.PICTURES_FILE, c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(DataAdapter.PICTURES_FILE)));
    startActivityForResult(i, PICTURES_ACTIVITY_START);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) 
{
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
    //Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
    switch(requestCode) 
    {
        default: break;
    }
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy()
{
    super.onDestroy();
    c.close();
    cnTable.close();
}
}
```

This is the error that I received:

01-19 10:29:24.158: E/AndroidRuntime(488): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.mp.Testing/com.mp.Testing.Testing}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "pictures": syntax error: pictures

Hope all can help me to resolve it and point out any error that I've written in my code. 
Thank you!

Comment: no need to use getApplicationContext() , you can use cnTable.open(this);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in SaveData, in the onCreate() method, it's not database.execSQL(DATABASE_TABLE_1); but database.execSQL(CREATE_DATABASE_TABLE_1);

Comment: Thank you! My app is able to run smoothly but the screen is empty. Unable to see the UI. Any idea what happen?

Comment: Is there any way the user save his/her name into the database and at the same time the name will be display on the next page?